# How to enable hands-free mode on Motorola MT2090?

Tags: c#, .net, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I have a Motorola MT2090 barcode scanner running a custom .net application that works fine as a handheld scanner by pulling the trigger.  What I'm trying to do is use the Motorolla Intellistand to enable hands-free mode, and keep the scanner on as barcodes are slid underneath it.  According to the user manual:

> When you insert the device into the stand’s
>   “cup,” the device’s built-in sensor places the device in presentation (hands-free) mode.

But this doesn't happen for me.  The scanner stays off and you still have to use the trigger.  I am using the Symbol.MT2000 libraries and I can't find anything in the API about programmatically enabling hands-free mode.  I also don't see any way to enable the scanner (like the trigger does) I can only catch the event.  Does anybody happen to know how to enable hands-free mode for one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the scanner in the stand and start your app the api will not toggle the presentation mode on. Either start the app and then place in the stand or lift the scanner tail an inch and drop it back to toggle it. There is magnet in the stand that triggers it. We are working with Moto to see if it can be handled better...

Comment: Thanks, I actually had a defective stand.  Replacement works perfectly.  Apparently the magnets weaken over time.